# What is a word that describes something that is easy to understand?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is a word that describes something that is easy to understand?

Just looking for a word that means something that is easy to understand.

Comment: What research have you done?  What words did you find and why didn't they work for you?      

From [the single-word-requests page](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info): To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**straightforward**

> straight·for·ward
>   ˌstrātˈfôrwərd/Submit
>   adjective
>   uncomplicated and easy to do or understand.
>   "in a straightforward case no fees will be charged"
>   synonyms:   uncomplicated, simple, easy, effortless, painless, undemanding, plain sailing, child's play; More
>   (of a person) honest and frank.
>   "a straightforward young man"
>   synonyms:   honest, frank, candid, open, truthful, sincere, on the level; More

note:  no great merit on my end.  search *easy to understand synonym* and you will get words for which *easy to understand* is a synonym.  which led me to straightforward.  I know it and it fits the bill.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps **intuitive**

> adjective in·tu·i·tive \ in-ˈtü-ə-tiv , -ˈtyü- \
>   readily learned or understood.
>   [*(Webster)*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/intuitive)

Example sentence:

> This software has an *intuitive* interface.

Answer (score 4):

I'll go with "comprehensible".

> adj. Readily comprehended or understood; intelligible.
>  [American
>   Heritage Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/comprehensible)

Example sentence:

> "I like this definition because it's really concise and
>   comprehensible, but are you allowed to use the word in the definition
>   of the word?"